# package.json on save does not trigger npm to update packages in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, npm, package.json, visual-studio-2022

After updating from Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio 2022 package.json no longer automatically triggers npm to update packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the project > show the properties window (F4) > change the setting "Restore On Save" in the "npm" section